# Deserialization using BinaryFormatter produces OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to get a client application to send a 'MessageObject' to a server application.

Every time I try to deserialize the MessageObject on the server, I get an OutOfMemoryException.

---

First of all, here is the **MessageObject** class:

```
[Serializable]
    public class MessageObject : ReplicableObject {
        public string Command;
        public string[] Parameters;

        public MessageObject() {

        }

        public MessageObject(string command, string[] parameters) {
            Command = command.ToLower();
            Parameters = parameters;
        }
    }
```

MessageObject is a child of **ReplicableObject**. Here is **ReplicableObject**:

```
[Serializable]
    public abstract class ReplicableObject {
        public string UniqueID {
            get {
                if (uniqueID == "" || uniqueID == null) {
                    uniqueID = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1990, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
                    uniqueID = uniqueID.Substring(uniqueID.Length / 2) + Engine.Random(1000000, 9999999).ToString();
                }
                return uniqueID; 
            }
            private set { uniqueID = value; }
        }
        private string uniqueID;

        [NonSerialized]
        public bool RequiresReplication = true;

        public ReplicableObject() {
            uniqueID = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1990, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
            uniqueID = uniqueID.Substring(uniqueID.Length / 2) + Engine.Random(1000000, 9999999).ToString();
        }
    }
```

When the client is ready to send a MessageObject to the server, this is the code it uses:

```
public static void SerializeRO(Stream stream, ReplicableObject ro) {
            Formatter.Serialize(stream, ro);
            stream.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("endhtobject"), 0, 11);
        }
```

**TerminationString** is:

```
public static byte[] TerminationString = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("endhtobject");
```

Once the server receives the data, this method is called (this is where the exception is thrown):

```
public static ReplicableObject CheckByteStringForRO(byte[] byteString) {
            int tStringIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < byteString.Length; ++i) {
                if (byteString[i] == TerminationString[tStringIndex]) {
                    ++tStringIndex;
                    if (tStringIndex >= TerminationString.Length) {
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        ms.Write(byteString, 0, i - 10);
                        ms.Position = 0;
                        ReplicableObject ro = (ReplicableObject) Formatter.Deserialize(ms);
                        ms.Close();
                        return ro;
                    }
                }
                else tStringIndex = 0;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Most of the above method is just searching for the TerminationString, so here are the important lines:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                            ms.Write(byteString, 0, i - 10);
                            ms.Position = 0;
                            ReplicableObject ro = (ReplicableObject) Formatter.Deserialize(ms);
                            ms.Close();
                            return ro;
```

---

On the line that starts 'ReplicableObject ro =', the OutOfMemoryException is thrown. I don't understand how this can happen, especially considering that the objects I'm sending are tiny.

I should point out that I'm new to sending serialized data over a network, so I may have done something wrong in that respect.

Please, leave a comment if you need clarification on anything. :)

Thank you.

---

Edit: Stack trace of exception as requested:

> mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryObjectWithMap.Read(System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary._*BinaryParser
>   input =
>   {System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.*_BinaryParser}) +
>   0x4f bytes
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary._*BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMap(System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryHeaderEnum
>   binaryHeaderEnum) + 0x38 bytes
>
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.*_BinaryParser.Run()
>   + 0x304 bytes
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler
>   handler = null,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser
>   serParser, bool fCheck, bool isCrossAppDomain,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage
>   = null) + 0xaf bytes
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream
>   serializationStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler
>   handler, bool fCheck, bool isCrossAppDomain,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCallMessage) + 0xcf bytes
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream
>   serializationStream) + 0x10 bytes
>
> > HolotypeTwo.dll!HolotypeTwo.Engine.CheckByteStringForRO(byte[]
> >     byteString = {byte[8192]}) Line 34 + 0x10 bytes   C# 
> >       HolotypeServer.exe!HolotypeServer.UnauthorisedPlayer.StartListening()
> >     Line 27 + 0x8 bytes   C# 
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object
> >     state) + 0x63 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xb0 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state) + 0x2c bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44
> >     bytes

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception

Comment: For start, don't write to memorystream, use the constructor that takes byte[] as an argument.  That is one obvious bug.

Comment: The stack trace suggests the OOM is real.  If these objects are tiny then the only thing that makes sense is that the data got scrambled somehow, producing a garbage value for "number of members".  Can't see the code that reads the byte[] from the stream.  A classic bug is not paying attention to the Read() method return value.

Comment: Continued: using a postfix to mark the end of the object is pretty painful.  The better approach is to first write an integer that gives the object size.  The receiver can now easily size the required buffer to read the object and knows exactly when to stop calling Read().

Comment: nonetheless, what I've done shouldn't cause this error, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the contents of what you are trying to Deserialize? You could be getting two objects in the stream occasionally due to a flaw in the code. Your CheckByteStringForRO method can end up skipping its termination marker if an 'e' byte occurs immediately before the marker. In order to properly catch that case your else condition needs to be:

```
else
{
    tStringIndex = 0;

    if (byteString[i] == TerminationString[tStringIndex])
    {
        tStringIndex++;
    }
}
```

Also, why not just make a collection of your objects and serialize that instead of using termination markers and all that?